# Minimum cost to group same characters in a string

Tags: string

I got stuck in a problem. The overall problem statement is big. I have solved the other pieces of it.
Got stuck in one piece.

Given a string containing some dashes('-') and some character lets say ('A'). Also, we are given with cost C to shift a character to its adjacent place. We need to find minimum cost such that all 'A' characters are grouped.

Example1: A-A--A---A and cost = 10

Minimum cost to group all 'A's would be: 80

Example2: AAAA------A and cost = 10

Minimum cost to group all 'A's would be: 60

Comment: You solve problems like this with pencil and paper and a deck of cards..Use hearts to represent the A's, and clubs to represent the dashes. Then start moving things around, keeping track of every step you take. Once you've solved the problem by hand, you should have written notes of how you did it. Then you can write the code. Remember, you solve the problem, *then* you write the code to implement your solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** for the cost to be minimum possible, one of the median As (2nd or 3rd of 4 in your first example, 3rd of 5 in your second example) can be left in place. Using this, you can compute the cost in O(n), where n is either the length of the string or the number of As, whichever is your input format.

Comment: Can be left in place meaning? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @FallAndLearn "can be left in place" = "can be never shifted to an adjacent place".

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this problem needs dynamic-programming.
You only need to move all A's towards the median A because this is the least total distance between all A's.

Just make sure not to move the media A. If the A at the median is moved to the right, each of the A's to its left will have to move one more step and each of the A's to its right will have to move one step less. This should cancel out, but you already added one unneeded step.